# Oracle SQL Developer freezes after renaming plsql package

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

If I rename the package and then compile the package, the SQL-Developer freezes. Is this is a known issue / are there any solutions for this behavior?

In earlier versions (f.e. 4.x)  a new package was created.

Add or remove functions and procedures is working, but not changing the name of the package. I made a screenshot after the sqldeveloper is frozen - I have to kill it with the windows taskmanager.

The new package is created, and I can edit it after I start a new sqldeveloper.

Thanks

SQL Developer Version 18.3.0.277 Oracle Database 12c

full jstack output: https://pastebin.com/VXZb2rSn

```
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Found 1 deadlock.
```

Comment: problem still exists (V19.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

Open a package (spec!)

```
create or replace PACKAGE PACKAGE_SO AS 

  /* TODO enter package declarations (types, exceptions, methods etc) here */ 

END PACKAGE_SO;
```

Take code, 'rename' the package.

```
create or replace PACKAGE PACKAGE_SO_NEW_NAME AS 

  /* TODO enter package declarations (types, exceptions, methods etc) here */ 

END PACKAGE_SO_NEW_NAME;
```

Compile.

[image]

I get a pop up dialog indicating a new package has been created, and after a brief pause, I get a new code editor.

[image]

My first package is no longer open.

I need to refresh the Package item on the tree to see the new one appear.

This is on version 18.3, using Java 8, on a Mac, against an 18c (12.2) database.

**Now, why is it not working for you?**

It appears the underlying framework code is trying to do user interface work on a non-UI thread, and it's getting stuck.

Not sure what's causing this condition for you and not for me, but this would be a bug.

Comment: I am working on Windows, different machines, different databases, but allways the same behavior.If I rename a existing package (spec or body) the developer crashes.

Comment: @systemlos if you indeed get a crash, share the java stack dump. if you're just getting an application freeze (not a crash) use the jstacke.exe in your java home bin dir and attach to the sql developer process ID to grab one - and share it here

Comment: you're right, it's a freeze. posted the jstack output

Comment: @systemlos there should be a LOT more there, that's not the full stack, only 2 threads worth

Comment: no, I did not undock the code editor. posted pastebin link.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith 19.1.0.094 Same, I edited the name of a spec and hit compile and it froze.  I wanted to create a duplicate with a different name (I wanted to just run the script but the "Run" option in spec view doesn't run the DDL but rather opens the EXECUTE proc dialog).